# Maximum velocity achieved by solar sail

Tags: interstellar-travel, solar-sail, velocity

What is the maximum (theoretical) velocity that can be achieved by solar-sail technology? Can we get close to the speed of light with that?

Comment: In the solar system ? Using only the sun as source of light ?

Comment: @Antzi a good answer would derive a simple equation, then allow one to plug in specific assumptions afterward. That would be a better way to go than *preconstraining* the question.

Comment: Hi @Tom11, is there anything else I can add to my answer?

Comment: Achieved or achievable? Lightsail2 is in orbit and gaining altitude but I don't know what the velocity is but most of it was not achieved by solar sail. My understanding is it is the first working example so it's maximum velocity would be the highest achieved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

> Can we get close to the speed of light with that?

No, at least not very easily. The terminal velocity $v_{\infty}$ is only about 0.2% the speed of light if you start at 1 AU using a 10 nanometer thick sail, and scales only as the inverse square root of the distance to the Sun where you start accelerating (as well as sail thickness), so you'd melt without getting much benefit from starting really close to it. Passing by a second stars helps little because you'd be going past it so quickly that you wouldn't get much of a second kick.

---

The relationship between the momentum and energy of a photon is $ p = E/c$, force is $dp/dt$, and acceleration is $F/m$. For a reflecting sail there is up to a factor of 2 for perfect reflection of normal incidence, and the total incident power (energy per unit time) would be the intensity $I$ of sunlight (energy per unit area per unit time) times the area $A$. So

$$a=\frac{F}{m} = \frac{2AI}{mc}.$$

To give this a test run, a one square kilometer sail made from a *futuristic* reflecting material with a thickness of 10 nanometers would weigh of order 10 kg. At 1 AU from the Sun, $I$ is about 1361 W/m^2 (the [Solar Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant)), giving an acceleration of 0.9 m/s^2 which is surprisingly big until you remember that you're redirecting a gigawatt of sunlight in the process.

If you balk at said futuristic 10nm thick mirror, a sub-wavelength spaced wire grid is discussed in the 1999 NASA Institute for Advanced Concepts report [Ultra-Thin Solar Sails for Interstellar Travel: Phase I Final Report](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/333Christensen.pdf) where values from 0.5 to 4 m/s^2 are plotted in Figure 7.

[image: Figure 7 Ultra-Thin Solar Sails for Interstellar Travel]

To get the asymptotic terminal velocity, we can make that work for all distances by normalizing to 1 AU :

$$a(r) = \frac{2AI}{mc} \frac{1AU}{r^2},$$

and then integrate it to infinity but unfortunately I can't remember how to solve differential equations any more, so I will cheat and use the result at the top of page 14 of that report:

$$v_{\infty} = 548,000 (m/s) \sqrt{a_{1AU} \frac{1AU}{r_{start}}},$$

which is only about 0.2% the speed of light starting at 1 AU, and scales only as the inverse square root of the distance to the Sun where you start accelerating.

> Table 1 shows some the missions that can be performed for an ultra-light solar sail. An ultra-thin sheet of aluminum only a few nanometers thick can achieve ac of ~0.3 m/s2, could reach Pluto in ~100 days, and reach the Oort cloud at ~10,000 AU within a century. In contrast, current propulsive methods would take over a decade to reach Pluto and are totally impractical to reach interstellar space. A perforated light sail made of aluminum could reach the Oort cloud in a half century if we can achieve ac >0.5 m/s2, and could do so in 12 years if ac ~5 m/s2
>    can be achieved. In the far term, a sail made of doped carbon nanotubes could probably approach the sun within 4 solar radii, and if it had an ac of 10 m/s2
>   , could reach α Centauri in a century. A sail made of doped carbon nanostructures could reach our nearest star in a few decades if ac >100 m/s2 as suggested
>   by extensions of microwave theory.
>
> It can thus be seen that the ultrathin solar sail holds the potential to revolutionize the prospects for interstellar travel. Uniquely, with this technology, such missions could not only become feasible, but potentially cheap, since all the motive power is provided in the form of crude sunlight – no giant lasers or other power systems are required.

[image: Table 1 Ultra-Thin Solar Sails for Interstellar Travel]

Comment: Let's stress out that (if i understand correctly) the results does NOT include any payload

Comment: @Antzi mass is of course total mass. It couldn't possibly be anything else.

Comment: @uhoh Could you explain in layman's terms why the limit is only 0.2% speed of light as opposed to the 10% cited here? http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/webproj/212_spring_2015/Robert_Miller/physics.html

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief The 0.2% value is what you get starting at 1 AU from the Sun, using a 10 nanometer thick sail. At different starting distances from the Sun and different sail thicknesses (and therefore masses) the terminal speed will of course be very different. The table at the end of the post lists conditions with $v_{infty}$ values as high as 13%, but that's starting at only 0.019 AU from the Sun (which is going to be extremely hot!) and probably with an extremely thin sail.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief I'm not going to debug the whole page you've linked to, but as soon as I saw 124 x 124 square feet = 15,376 square meters I realized there were going to be problems, and even with 31.76 kilograms over  15,376 square meters the areal density is 2 grams per square meter which at a density of 1 g/cm^3 would be 2 microns thick, which is 200 times thicker and heavier than my assumptions. So the sail described there is never going to get close to 10% the speed of light. If you want a complete debugging of the page I recommend you ask a new question.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief but these are 128 different "web projects" that someone has "received" as of May 12, 2015, for what I assume is a class such as Physics 212 (which comes [right after Physics 211](https://www.uaf.edu/physics/files/BS_PHYS_advising_flow_chart.pdf). They look like student reports, rather than authoritative sources. If you explain all that in a question and ask how they managed to get to 10% of the speed of light without using calculus, I think someone (but not I) might take the time to debug that report for you.

Comment: @uhoh Thanks. I was directed here from worldbuilding stack exchange hoping to create a ficitonal world that uses more realistic/plausible science. I found that paper as a top result from Google search's recommended answer when looking for top speed of solar sails. Someone told me my assumption of solar sails traveling at 10% speed of light wouldn't work, citing your answer here. I will probably re-ask my question at worldbuilding and drop a link here in case you're interested in entertaining sci-fi scenarios.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief I'll take a look sure! I'm not sure I could contribute, but looking forward to reading about it. *Thanks!*

Comment: What about adding a high powered laser positioned in L2? How much velocity could it realistically add?

Comment: @SafeFastExpressive that's a new question, and not an easy one!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that photons are hitting the sail at an unchanging rate and removing variables such as gravity, obstacles, and anything else that would impede the crafts movement then
theoretically, yes it is possible to approach the speed of light. However the faster you went the longer it would take to significantly accelerate the craft. This means it could take thousands of years if not more to actually reach the speed of light. Think of it this way. Two race car drivers are moving at different speeds. Car 1 is 20 feet in front of Car 2 yet, Car 1 is moving slower than Car 2, behind him . At this rate Car 2 will eventually catch up to Car 1 after a certain period of time. But if Car 1 speeds up it will take longer for Car 2 to catch up to Car 1. Car 1 is like the Solar Sail while, Car 2 is the Photon hitting the sail. In short, it is possible to reach the speed of light with a Solar Sail, however doing so in real life even outside of the solar system is very, very unlikely.

Comment: It looks like you are describing the doppler shift with your car analogy. Note that photons always travel at the speed of light for every observer, unlike the cars. As the sail moves faster relative to the light source, this doppler shift reduces the momentum & energy that each photon carries, even if the relative speed of the photons is constant.

Comment: From the other answer that describes the terminal velocity of a solar sail, it seems that you'd have to cruise past multiple stars for this to work - as you accelerate away from the sun, fewer and fewer photons hit the sail, causing the acceleration to approach 0 and velocity to level off. You'd have to fold up the sail and wait until you're near another star to unfurl it again to pick up more speed, and that interstellar cruise will take a *long* time.

Answer (score 1):

**6.47% speed of light is the engineering limit.**

Here are two key factors that determines the terminal velocity $v$.

1. $\sigma$: **areal density of the solar sail.**
2. $r_0$: **perihelion distance.**

For solar sail material, single layer graphene is the lightest material so far, and it has the largest areal density $\sigma =7.626 \times 10^{−7} kg/m^2$.

For perihelion distance, it is at least the radius of the sun, which is $r_0 = 6.9634\times 10^8 m$.

Assume the solar sail has surface area 1 square meter (then its mass is $\sigma$) and absorbs 100% light.
Let's say the solar sail travels from distance $r_0$ to infinity.
Theoretically, the total energy received from sun's radiational pressure is

$E = \int_{r_0}^{\infty}  \frac{P_{au} r_{au}^2}{r^2} dr = \frac{P_{au} r_{au}^2}{r_0}$，

Where $r_{au} = AU = 1.49 \times 10^{11} m$ is the  Astronomical Unit and $P_{au} = 4.5\times 10^{-6} N/m^2$ is the light pressure at distance 1 AU.

With Energy Conservation $E = \frac{1}{2} \sigma v^2$, we get terminal velocity

$v = \sqrt{ \frac{2 P_{au} r_{au}^2 }{\sigma r_0}} = 19,397,620 m/s  = $ 6.47% c

**"Too Optimistic:"**

1. A single layer of graphene absorbs a mere 2.3% of incident light, allowing around 97.7% to pass through.
2. the single layer graphene sheet can hardly survive the high temperature near the sun's surface.
3. Most acceleration happens within 0.1 AU, which is around 20 times of the sun's radius.

In practice, the closest solar probe is around 10 times sun's radius. And if we also consider graphene transmittance, we get terminal velocity

$v' = \sqrt{0.023 / 10 } v = $ 0.31 % c.