# What is the functional form for r(t) for a solar-sail deorbit into the Sun?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, solar-sail

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30273/12102) describes a spacecraft in a heliocentric orbit using a solar sail to "deorbit" into the Sun by reflecting sunlight into *roughly* the prograde direction. In comments it was proposed that while the solar flux and therefore thrust of the sail increases as the craft gets closer to the Sun, the delta-v required for a given change in orbit size increases as well.

For a spacecraft of mass $m$ and perfectly reflecting sail area $A$, what does the plot of orbit radius versus time $r(t)$ look like? Is it a straight line, power law ($p \neq 1$), exponential, logarithmic, or something else?

Since the answer mentions that a reflector angle of 45°, resulting in exactly prograde thrust is not necessarily the optimum, you are welcome to consider either 45° or the optimum angle, fixed or dynamic (though I don't think it would change with distance).

"bonus points" for the derivation of $r(t)$!

Comment: Well-- if a craft like this is ever designed it absolutely must be called ICARUS.

Comment: Probably solution is not an analytical function.

Comment: @Heopps for a circular orbit or a slow spiral, I'll bet it is! Let's see what happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes that the spacecraft stays in an almost-circular orbit all the time. We have
$$
\frac{dE}{dt} = F_\tau v,
$$
where $E$ is spacecraft's energy (potential + kinetic), $v$ is its speed, and $F_\tau$ is the tangential component of the solar pressure force. For a circular orbit, $E\propto -\frac1r$ (so $\frac{dE}{dt}\propto \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{dr}{dt}$) and $v\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$. As long as the angle between the sail and the direction to the sun stays constant (whether it's optimal or not), $F_\tau\propto -\frac{1}{r^2}$. So we have
$$
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{dr}{dt} \propto -\frac{1}{r^{5/2}},
$$
or
$$
\frac{dr}{dt} \propto - \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}.
$$

A solution of a differential equation like this has the form
$$
r(t) \propto (T - t)^{2/3},
$$
where $T$ (which is greater than the starting time) is determined by the starting conditions and the proportionality coefficient in the equation.

Comment: okay it looks like the onus is on me to check it, I'll give it a go in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Sorry, I made a mistake. The power should be 2/3, not 2.

Comment: That looks better! It also appears to have the same shape as my simulation (I'll post something soon). Also, I think $T$ is "greater than (or equal to) the *finish* time" as well. Exponentiation to fractional powers returns complex numbers for negative arguments, for example $-1^{2/3}=-1/2+\sqrt{3/4}j$ So probably $T$ may end up being just the arrival time itself, since $r(t)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like @Litho's answer [nailed it](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30314/12102)!

> $$ r(t) \propto (T - t)^{2/3} $$

I did a quick simulation based on the Planetary Society's [LightSail 2](http://www.planetary.org/explore/projects/lightsail-solar-sailing/lightsail-faqs.html)'s spec of 5kg and 32 m^2 sail area. I fixed it at a reflector angle of 45° so that the pressure from sunlight results in a radial force outward (momentum of the incident light) plus a a tangential force prograde (momentum of the reflected light).

The acceleration due to the momentum of light either striking or leaving a surface is just

$$\frac{AI}{mc} = \frac{AI_0}{mc} \left(\frac{\text{1 AU}}{r}\right)^2$$

where $I_0$ is the solar constant (intensity at 1 AU) of about 1361 W/m^2. See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25746/12102) for more on solar pressure and acceleration by solar sails. Remember to divide the area of the sail by $\sqrt{2}$ to get the *projected area* at 45°.

I started in a circular orbit at 1 AU and integrated for 15.35 years.

It turns out that $T$ is the arrival time, so in the first plot I just compare $r$, the distance to the Sun in the simulation, to the simple expression:

> $$ \text{1 AU} \left(1 - \frac{t}{T}\right)^{2/3} $$

and *voilà a perfect fit!* The wiggles are due to the fact that I started with a heliocentric circular orbit of 1 AU and a velocity of $\sqrt{GM_{Sun}/1 AU} =$ 29783 m/s with the solar pressure effects at full strength (deceleration, slight outward force reducing gravity, and so the orbit is very slightly elliptical.

*Radial* accelerations due to the Sun's gravity and incident radiation pressure are given by:

$$-\frac{GM}{r^2} \ \ \text{and} \ \  +\frac{AI_0}{\sqrt{2}mc}  \frac{\text{1 AU}^2}{r^2}$$

Numerically at 1 AU they are 5.930E-03 and 2.053E-05 m/s^2 respectively, and because both scale as $1/r^2$ the ratio of the two is fixed and independent of distance. In this case the ratio is about 289:1.

[image]

[image]

```
def deriv (X, t):

    r,  v  = X.reshape(2, -1)
    nr, nv = [thing / np.sqrt((thing**2).sum()) for thing in (r, v)] # normals
    rsqAU  = (r**2).sum() / AUsq

    acc_g     = -GMs * r * ((r**2).sum())**-1.5
    acc_solar = (Area/np.sqrt(2.) * I_zero / (m * c) / rsqAU) * (nr - nv) # radially out, and prograde

    return np.hstack((v, acc_g + acc_solar))

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint

halfpi, pi, twopi = [f*np.pi for f in (0.5, 1, 2)]
degs, rads        = 180/pi, pi/180

AU     = 1.495978707E+11       # m
AUsq   = AU**2                 # m^2

GMs  = 1.327E+20               # m^3/s^2

km   = 1000.                   # meters
year = 365.2564 * 24. * 3600.  # seconds

# http://www.planetary.org/explore/projects/lightsail-solar-sailing/lightsail-faqs.html
m      = 5.                    # kg
c      = 3E+08                 # m/s
I_zero = 1361.                 # 1361 W/m^2 (at 1 AU)
Area   = 32.                   # m^2

time = np.arange(0, 15.35*year, 1E+05)  # seconds

v0    = np.sqrt(GMs/AU)

X0    = np.array([AU, 0, 0, v0])

print "X0: ", X0

answer, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, time, rtol=1E-10, full_output=True)

print answer.shape

x, v = answer.T.reshape(2, 2, -1)
r    = np.sqrt((x**2).sum(axis=0))
x, y = x

if True:
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(x/km, y/km)
    plt.title('heliocentric de-orbit (km)')
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(time/year, x/km)
    plt.plot(time/year, y/km)
    plt.plot(time/year, r/km, '-r', linewidth=2)
    plt.title('x, y and r (km) vs time (years)')
    plt.show()

if True:
    T0 = time.max()
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(time/year, r/km)
    plt.plot(time/year, AU*(1-time/T0)**(2./3)/km)
    plt.title('r and  AU(1-t/15.35)^(2/3) (km) vs time (years)')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Way to check the answer, or answer the check, maybe. I appreciate you putting in the code, so I can play around with it, too.

Comment: I already like this community, because people share useful things. : ) Thanks!